# 2-huge cardinal, the most usual definition

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, large-cardinals

How are *2-huge cardinals* usually defined?

Is the definition contained in Jech's set theory book (the millennium edition)? Which page?

Comment: Is there any reason to be dissatisfied with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huge_cardinal#Variants?

Comment: This is a good reference. However I'd like to see where it is in the Jech's book to also see some surrounding theorems,lemmas and facts.

Comment: @To amWhy: I'm just curious what was your edit? I clicked edited but I couldn't see any difference from my original post.

Comment: Do @amWhy with the “@“ in front of their name so they get pinged. The edit history looks to me like they corrected a spacing typo and placed “Is the definition...” on a new line.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I could not have done @ amWhy as he was then the only commentator . In this case @ does not work automatically.

Comment: @user122424  In your second line, the two questions were run-on sentences, reading "Is the definition contained in Jech's millennium edition?Which page?"  I very minor edit.  We like to help users to present their questions in best form: spelling changes when needed, help with mathjax when needed, or correcting grammatical mishaps and typos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jech defines huge cardinals in definition 20.26 on page 380 in my version:

*Definition 20.26.* A cardinal $\kappa$ is a *huge cardinal* if there exists an elementary embedding $j \colon V \to M$ ($M$ transitive) with critical point $\kappa$ such that $M^{j(\kappa)} \subseteq M$.

*Definition p.386* A cardinal $\kappa$ is *$n$-huge* if there exists an elementary embedding $j \colon V \to M$ ($M$ transitive) with critical point $\kappa$ such that $M^{j^n(\kappa)} \subseteq M$.

At the end of the same chapter there are some exercises about huge and $n$-huge cardinals (see 20.13, 20.14 and 20.15).

Comment: Other reasonable references: Kanamori's book. Cantor's attic.